# Blazor .NET Core 7 which layout file to use? _host.cshtml and _layouts.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor with .NET Core 7. The out-of-the-box project comes with `_hosts` file. But cshtml files do not use `_host` but use `_layouts`. I have seen several projects pointing the `_host` file to a `_layout` file. This way there is only one file that can be used by the different file types.

Am I losing any functionality doing this?

An example of `_hosts` file configured to use `_layout` file.

```
@page "/"

@namespace BlazorApp1.Pages

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so.

Net6.0 switched to the _Host/_Layout pattern for some reason.  Net7.0 switched back to the single file _Host file pattern used in Net5.0 and earlier releases.

Answer (score 0):

`_Host.cshtml` is the root RazorPage of the Blazor application ,all your razor components would be rendered on it.It's not a [layout page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for it dosen't contain `@RenderBody()/@RenderSection()`

The default parttern is  similar with MrC aka Shaun Curtis's answer(In .net 6,it just specifies where the root App component (App.razor) is rendered. In .net 7,_layout.cshtml is removed,all codes were moved to _Host.cshtml),but you could spcific a layout page  for _host.cshtml and seperate the codes yourself

[image]

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/project-structure?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-server) related with project structure of Blazor App may help

> _Host.cshtml: The root page of the app implemented as a Razor Page: When any page of the app is initially requested, this page is rendered
> and returned in the response. The Host page specifies where the root
> App component (App.razor) is rendered.

> _Layout.cshtml: The layout page for the _Host.cshtml root page of the app.